# Spresense 拡張ボードが動作しない

Tags: spresense

Spresense メインボードと拡張ボードを接続したのですが、拡張ボードを認識しません。
もちろん、接続はしっかりはめ込んでいます。

・拡張ボードのUSBを繋げても、SDカードとして認識しない
・拡張ボードのアナログ、デジタルの各ピンも、スケッチから制御できない
・拡張ボードのVout、3.3Vは電気が来ている（拡張ボードのUSBを繋げても、いなくても）

２セットあるのですが、同じ現象なので、私の使い方だと思うのですが、ご教授おねがいします。

Answer (score 2):

私も最初の頃、はまったことがあるのですが、恐らくメインボードと拡張ボードのB2Bコネクタの接続ではないかと思います。（中途半端に動くことがあるので、非常に質が悪い…）

メインボードを拡張ボードに接続するときにカチッと音がするので篏合したかと思うのですが、スペーサーが嵌っただけで B2Bコネクタが十分に接続されていないことがよくあります。メインボードを上からしっかりと押しこんでみてください。意外と丈夫なので思いっきり押し込んでも問題ありません。めり込む感覚があれば、B2Bコネクタの接続の問題です。

あと、拡張ボードの IO電圧は 3.3V と 5.0V がジャンパーで選択可能となっているので、そこも気をつけてください。ジャンパーは電源コネクタの上のほうにあります。

また、拡張ボード上の USB を Mass Storage Class として動かすには、明示的にプログラムをしないといけません。 Arduino IDE の ”ファイル” -> "スケッチ例" -> "SDHCI" -> "UsbMsc" もしくは "UsbMscAndFileOpeation" にサンプルスケッチがあります。

以上、ご参考になれば

Comment: Yoshino Taro さん
早速のご回答、ありがとうございます。
めり込む感覚にならないのです、ハマったかんじはするのです、
相当力を入れて、何度もやっているのですが...

Comment: 念のため、次のチュートリアルを参考に確認をしてみてはいかがでしょうか？　https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/set-up-the-arduino-ide

Comment: Yoshino Taro さん、情報ありがとうございます、チュートリアルは再度行ってみました
先週はMACで行ったのですが、今日ははWindowsででも現象は同じです

UsbMsc、UsbMscAndFileOpeationも動きません、SD.begin()が0を返してしまってます
USBを繋げても、SDカードとして認識しません
あ

Comment: SDカードのフォーマットを確認すべきかもしれませんね。FAQに次の記述がありました。”Spresense で扱えるフォーマットはFAT32のみです”、”Spresense は、マルチパーティションのファイルシステムをサポートしていません”。あと、SDカードの種類も関係しているかも知れません。SDXCでは認識しないようです。Twitter に次のやりとりを見つけました。"https://twitter.com/spresense/status/1152352724245049344"

Comment: SDHCのFAT21フォーマットで１Gと２G２つでやってみましたが、ダメですした。

Comment: FAT32 のTypoですよね？ 1G や 2G とは随分古めのSDカードですね。質問の再確認になってしまいますが、（１）拡張ボード上のSDカードスロットにSDカードを挿し、（２）メインボードのUSBコネクタからSPRESENSEメインボードにUsbMscを書き込み、（３）拡張ボードのUSBコネクタとPCを接続したところ、（４）拡張ボードに挿したSDカードがPCからドライブとして見えない。ということですよね？

Comment: arduinoのライブラリが多数入っているので、全て削除して、再度ArduinoIDEのインストールからやり直したところ、解決しました。

そもそもの原因は、わからないのですが、とりあえず、動くようになりました。
いろいろアドバイスありがとうございます。